# Optimise SWF loading time

Tags: jquery, html

so I have an swf file on my webpage that is displayed on the press of a button. I am currently using the jquery hide function to hide the html block of code that containts the swf. The problem is, it takes a few seconds to load after pressing the button. Is there a way that I can optimise the loading time? Maybe somehow "load" the swf when the page actually loads then just display it when the button is clicked? Thanks.

Comment: you could load it into a div with CSS visibility:hidden then just $('#button').css({'visibility':'visible'});

Comment: I tried that also, same result.

Comment: how are you 'loading' the swf? Are you using `swfobject`?

Comment: @ahren `<OBJECT id="rice" style="z-index:2; position:absolute; top:20%; left:15%;" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="90%" HEIGHT="70%" id="rice" ALIGN=""><PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="rice.swf"><PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=low><EMBED src="rice.swf" quality=low bgcolor=#EEEEEE WIDTH="90%" HEIGHT="90%" NAME="rice" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED> </OBJECT>`

Comment: This might sound strange but set the css of the container of the swf to display:block. Then with $(document).ready() hide the container. This should still trigger the download of the swf file. Check the Net tab in firebug to see if it downloads. If that doesn't work, you could simply place the container outside the page {position:absolute; top:-9999px; left:-9999px;} for it to load. Then place it correctly. It's not the best of the solutions but might just work. BUT if you have sound in your swf, the audio will be enable which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tuts+ Preloaders](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow/the-comprehensive-guide-to-preloading-a-single-swf-file/)

Suggestion would be to use the preloader in Flash. swf files don't really get preloaded like an image can be. See Link above.

Another alternative is to load the swf upon opening the page and then have it stop right after your preloader plays effectively pausing the play then once the user clicks the button have it jump to the next frame to continue playing the rest of your swf.

Comment: **Another alternative is to load the swf upon opening the page and then have it stop right after your preloader plays effectively pausing the play then once the user clicks the button have it jump to the next frame to continue playing the rest of your swf.** How would I do that?